# Android:app creation malfunction(Implicit Intent)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-manifest, android-implicit-intent

I have two applications where the one opens by `implicit intent`the other one.So in the first application I create an Intent and where I wrote `i.setAction("com.example.secondApp");`and I launch it through `startActivity(i);`

Then on the second app I change the manifest(filter) like:

```
  <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.example.secondApp" />

           <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
```

plus I do all the creation intent in the java section.

*code tested because everything was done by explicit intent in the first place and worked fine

So my point is when I try to run them both the first app installs nicely where the second one says that 
`No Launcher activity found!`obviously cause I changed it but despite it installs it isn't shown on the phone nor the first App detects the second one,any clue?

*Also when I leave the manifest(filter) of the second app at default values it installs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an activity to appear in the launcher, it needs the appropriate `<intent-filter>`:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

If you want that activity to have *another* `<intent-filter>`, that is fine. An `<activity>` can have as many `<intent-filter>` elements as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't know you can put as many filters as you want.I added in my intent-filter your choice too(default) and know it worked fine,thanks a lot.